# com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 541 5.4.1 Content blocked by Internal Firewall

Tags: java

I am getting 541 5.4.1 Content blocked by Internal Firewall exception when i am sending a email in java. I have to send a calendar event so i am using String buffer and appending the content, when iam setting the content and sending email , i am getting blocked by internet firewall.
Below iam keeping the code.

```
public void send(Appointment appointment, String host) throws Exception {

        try {

            Properties prop = new Properties();
            prop.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
            prop.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
            prop.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");

            Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop, null);
            // Define message
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.addHeaderLine("method=REQUEST");
            message.addHeaderLine("charset=UTF-8");
            message.addHeaderLine("component=VEVENT");

            String toMa = StringUtils.getCommaDelimitedStringfromStringList(appointment.getTo());
            String ccMa = StringUtils.getCommaDelimitedStringfromStringList(appointment.getCc());

            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(appointment.getFrom()));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(toMa));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.CC, InternetAddress.parse(ccMa));
            message.setSubject(appointment.getSubject());
            message.setHeader("Content-class", "urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");

            String content = getICSString2(appointment, message);

            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Class", "urn:content-  
  classes:calendarmessage");
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "calendar_message");
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(content, "text/calendar")));// very
                                                                                                                // important

            // Create a Multipart
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Add part one
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // send message
            Transport.send(message);
        }
        catch (MessagingException me) {
            me.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

private String getICSString2(Appointment appointment, MimeMessage message) {

        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

        str.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.append("PRODID: Asset View 2.0");
        str.append("METHOD:REQUEST");
        str.append("BEGIN:VEVENT");

        str.append("DTSTAMP:" + extracted(FORMATED_DATE_TIME, 0, null));

        if (appointment.isIsAllDayEvent()) {

            str.append("DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:" + extracted(FORMATED_DATE, 0, appointment.getStartDate()));
            str.append("DTEND;VALUE=DATE:" + extracted(FORMATED_DATE, 1, appointment.getStartDate()));

        }
        else {
            str.append("DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:" + extracted(FORMATED_DATE_TIME, 0, appointment.getStartDate()));
            str.append("DTEND;VALUE=DATE:" + extracted(FORMATED_DATE_TIME, 0, appointment.getEndDate()));
        }

        createRecurringEvents(appointment, str);
        str.append("LOCATION: " + appointment.getLocation());
        str.append(String.format("UID:%s", UUID.randomUUID().toString()));
        str.append(String.format("DESCRIPTION:%s", appointment.getContent()));
        str.append(String.format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:%s", appointment.getContent()));
        str.append(String.format("SUMMARY:%s", appointment.getSubject()));
        str.append(String.format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:%s", appointment.getFrom()));
        str.append(String.format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"%s\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:%s",
                appointment.getTo().stream().findFirst().orElse(null),
                appointment.getTo().stream().findFirst().orElse(null)));
        str.append("X-MICROSOFT-CDO-BUSYSTATUS:FREE");

        str.append("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.append("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.append("DESCRIPTION:REMINDER");
        str.append("TRIGGER:-P1D");
        str.append("END:VALARM");

        str.append("END:VEVENT");
        str.append("END:VCALENDAR");

        return str.toString();
    }
```

Comment: The error message is explicit: your machine has an internal Firewall that has not be configured to allow the Java virtual machine to send mails. So it rejects the connection and provides its error message and the smtp library makes it available in its exception message. So it is not a programming problem but a system configuration one (hence a comment and not an answer).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by properly setting the content string.

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        StringBuffer buffer = sb.append("BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n"+
        "PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 9.0 MIMEDIR//EN\n"+
        "VERSION:2.0\n" +
        "METHOD:REQUEST\n" +
        "BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
"ATTENDEE;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;RSVP=TRUE:"+appointment.getTo().stream().findFirst().orElse(null)+"\n" +
        "ORGANIZER:MAILTO:"+appointment.getFrom()+"\n" +
        "DTSTART:"+extracted(FORMATED_DATE_TIME, 0, appointment.getStartDate())+"\n" +
        "DTEND:"+extracted(FORMATED_DATE, 1, appointment.getEndDate())+"\n" +
        "LOCATION:"+appointment.getLocation()+"\n" +
        "TRANSP:OPAQUE\n" +
        "SEQUENCE:0\n" +
"UID:040000008200E00074C5B7101A82E00800000000002FF466CE3AC5010000000000000000100\n" +
        " 000004377FE5C37984842BF9440448399EB02\n" +
        "DTSTAMP:"+extracted(FORMATED_DATE_TIME, 0, null)+"\n" +
        "CATEGORIES:Meeting\n" +
        "DESCRIPTION:"+appointment.getContent()+"\n" +
        "SUMMARY:"+appointment.getSubject()+"\n" +
        "PRIORITY:5\n" +
        "CLASS:PUBLIC\n" +
        "BEGIN:VALARM\n" +
        "TRIGGER:PT1440M\n" +
        "ACTION:DISPLAY\n" +
        "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\n" +
        "END:VALARM\n" +
        "END:VEVENT\n" +
        "END:VCALENDAR");
        
        return buffer.toString();
    }
```

Comment: OK ... the problem was that the content was malformed because you left out all of the newlines.